# convert attribute values into an object (jquery or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such attribute in my element:

```
data-variations="{"2005":"11.99","2006":"15.99","2007":"19.99"}"
```

Is there any way to convert it into an object, which can look like:

```
obj = {2005:11.99, 2006:15.99, 2007:19.99}
```

I've tried first to get this attribute as string and split it with "," for further manipulations, but realized that there must be better and cleaner solution

Comment: The `data` method automatically parses attribute values that contain JSON. The only thing you'd have to do is iterate over the object and convert the values to numbers (or of course simply store them as numbers in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a JSON string.  You can use `JSON.parse()` to parse it as an object.

Actually, since you are using jQuery, it will do that *for you* if you use `.data()`.

```
var obj = $(element).data('variations')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var text = "{"2005":"11.99","2006":"15.99","2007":"19.99"}";
```

obj = JSON.parse(text);

$.each(obj, function(k, v) {

//use k as key and v as value

});